# justify center antd form

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

Here trying to justify: center this Antd form, but these two cols labelCol and wrapperCol spans seems to prevent it, removing those cols it seems to work, is there a way to center this form and still have those spans(or remove cols and have its functionality other way?) ?

test1.tsx:

```html
    <div> <Form.Item
        labelCol={{
          span: 2,
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 14,
        }}
        label="name"
        name="name"
      >
        <Input type="string" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        labelCol={{
          span: 2,
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 14,
        }}
        label='address'
        name="address"
      >
        <Input type="string" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        labelCol={{
          span: 2,
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 14,
        }}
        label='businessId'
        name="businessId"
      >
        <Input type="string" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        labelCol={{
          span: 2,
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 14,
        }}
        label='phone'
        name="phone"
      >
        <Input type="string" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        labelCol={{
          span: 2,
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 14,
        }}
        label='email'
        name="email"
      >
        <Input type="string" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        labelCol={{
          span: 2,
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 14,
        }}
        key="sendEmail"
        label='endEmail'
      >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="sendEmailOnDelivery"
          name="sendEmailOnDelivery"
        />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          submmit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
```

: inside test2.tsx:

```
<div className="customer">
    <Form name="createCustomer">
      <Test1 />
    </Form>
  </div>
```

my css:

```html
.customer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#createCustomer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `createCustomer` class to:

```
#createCustomer {
  width: 75%;
}
```

And `labelCol` and `wrapperCol` in the `Form.Item`'s as:

```
labelCol={{
    span: 4
}}
wrapperCol={{
    span: 18
}}
```

Working demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4150-forked-ytiw3).

Comment: could you check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868797/antd-select-option-with-search-functionality

Comment: have time to check that other also ?

Comment: Currently busy, will check after some hours, InShaAllah.

Comment: Inshallah brother

Comment: Hello brother, @walee.