# antd select option with search functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

i dont know if this is possible but at the moment when user click from select options it will take to that specific url, my point is can we have search functionality in 'Search...' so user could search from hundreds of option and then choose it and click the button and that button should also take to that same 'onChange' address. You can also suggest other options, even without select but functionality must be same , here is my code:

```js
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Select } from "antd";
// import { Link, useHistory, useRouteMatch, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function EventsSection() {
  // const history = useHistory();
  const { Option } = Select;

  // const changeHandler = (id) => {
  //   history.push(`/customer/${id}`);
  // };
  return (
    <div>
      {/* when found in search i want this button take to  'onChange' address also*/}
      <button>click me when found in search</button>
      <Select
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        placeholder="Search..."
        mode="multiple"
        open={true}
        listHeight={128}
        // onChange={changeHandler}
      >
        <Option value="1">Not Identified</Option>
        <Option value="2">Closed</Option>
        <Option value="3">Communicated</Option>
        <Option value="4">Identified</Option>
        <Option value="5">Resolved</Option>
        <Option value="6">Cancelled</Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EventsSection;
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, brother. But I'm not getting your requirement properly.

Comment: There where is written ’search...’ user should be able to search, for example by writing first letters cl it gets ’Closed’ from that drop down and then that button can be cliked which should take user to that ’onChange’

Comment: As can be seen from photo above

Comment: Hey @walee, did you check the updated answer?

Comment: Please recheck.

Comment: edited picture if it is possible to have some functionality lite that would appreciate, if not then i can accept your this answer also.

Comment: So, chosen option will removed from options then? You were navigating to another page. What about that?

Comment: Hey @walee, are you there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is done.
Check at [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4150-forked-4lnb3?file=/index.js).

The second part is still unclear to me.

Exactly this part

> and then that button can be cliked which should take user to that
> ’onChange’

Comment: Done. please recheck the URL.

Comment: Could you add that div ?

Comment: Please recheck.

Comment: There is a close option. And you cannot press the button without selecting it. Check console for selected value and text.

Comment: And please upvote and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Now its inside input, possible to have it as div outside and clickable, this is also ok i mean, but that would be better

Comment: Done, don't ask for more. And accept the answer.

Comment: could you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022349/change-switch-main-path-according-to-api